# How to fix the exception type: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 6; 2 is required

Tags: python, html, django

I received this from running the server on my Django project. http://dpaste.com/0D1PS4A This is the code I used for my project:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<table>
  <tr><th>Game ID</th><th>Game Name</th><th>Hours Played</th></tr>
  {% for game in games %}
    {# each game object is a dictionary with "appid", "name " and "playtime_forever" keys #}
    <tr><td>{{ game.appid }}</td><td>{{game.name}} </td><td>{{ game.playtime_forever }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock content %}
```

Array passed:

```
[{u'appid': 4000, 
  u'has_community_visible_stats': True, 
  u'img_icon_url': u'd9101cbeddcc4ff06c7fa1936c3f381b0bbf2e92',
  u'img_logo_url': u'dca12980667e32ab072d79f5dbe91884056a03a2', 
  u'name': u"Garry's Mod", 
  u'playtime_forever': 0},
```

Comment: No need of `{% endblock content %}` , just `{% endblock %}` and comments should be `{% comment %} comments line {% endcomment %}`

Comment: Hmmm now I get this error: http://dpaste.com/0TXBHDB

Comment: {% block content %} this should be same as yours. I told for `endblock` only.Also is there `block content` in your base.html?

Comment: Is it a typo or are you  not closing your list?

Comment: No there isn't. in the base.html. Still getting the error though. http://dpaste.com/0D1PS4A

Comment: `block content` should be there in your `base.html.Otherwise just remove these lines and check working {% extends "base.html" %}, {% block content %}, {% endblock content %}.But this should be inside <html> tag

Comment: Hmm... if I remove the block content and the extend base.html, what would I need to replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are extending from any html and adding contents as `block`, There should be defined `block` in the root hml.In order to test your html.Simply

`yours.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<table>
  <tr><th>Game ID</th><th>Game Name</th><th>Hours Played</th></tr>
  {% for game in games %}
    {# each game object is a dictionary with "appid", "name " and "playtime_forever" keys #}
    <tr><td>{{ game.appid }}</td><td>{{game.name}} </td><td>{{ game.playtime_forever }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
</html>
```

`views.py`

```
games = [{u'appid': 4000, 
          u'has_community_visible_stats': True, 
          u'img_icon_url': u'd9101cbeddcc4ff06c7fa1936c3f381b0bbf2e92',
          u'img_logo_url': u'dca12980667e32ab072d79f5dbe91884056a03a2', 
          u'name': u"Garry's Mod", 
          u'playtime_forever': 0}]
return render(
    request, 
    'yours.html', 
    {
        "games": games
    }
)
```